# Converting a Unix Sort command into a Quicksort

Tags: c, unix, sorting, cmd, quicksort

I have a command `sort -n +1 -2 -o /tmp/ord_id` in a C file that i call using system, which is pretty bad. How would i go about creating a quicksort function to complete the same tasks that the unix command will do? Here is how the command is called:

```
static const char sortcmd[] = "sort -n +1 -2 -o /tmp/ord_id "; //dec during function
//later in the function
bu_vls_strcpy(&cmd, sortcmd); //ONLY NEED TO FIX THIS COMMAND
bu_vls_strcat(&cmd, argv[1]);
bu_vls_printf(&gedp->ged_result_str, "%V\n", &cmd);
(void)system( bu_vls_addr(&cmd) );
```

bu_vls functions are predefined in the program,  so think of them like the usual string functions. i commented the line of code that the call appears, any tips or code is appreciated(this is not a homework assignment, independent project!)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few steps:

1. Read in the file (assuming that's `argv[1]`)
2. (optional) Parse it to find the fields selected by the `+1 -2` using the same rules as sort.
3. Write a sort predicate to implement sorting with numeric sort for numbers (from the `-n`) argument.  This either operates on full lines (if you skipped step 2) or on the structure you created to represent the parsed line.
4. Call `qsort`
5. Write the data out in sorted order.

Comment: is qsort a predefined function? If so is it appart of the cstdlib?

Comment: how would i write to the file specified? would i need to create a FILE object and write to the object after the sort with argv[1]?

Comment: The output file is selected by `-o /tmp/ord_id` (which is not a particularly good way to make a temp file, but if you want to copy the existing behavior...) so you would need to open and write to that file explicitly.